# TaxonomyClientService GetTermSets - Error The maximum string content length quota (65535) has been exceeded while reading XML data

Tags: client-object-model, configuration

I'm using the TaxonomyClientService to retrieve the TermSets using the GetTermSets call, the code works fine except one of the result is getting big and I'm receiving this error

> The maximum string content length quota (65535) has been exceeded
>   while reading XML data

I have increased the **maxStringContentLength** on the client side already and it's still returning the same error.  So I think the problem is on the SharePoint Server side where I will need to increase limit.

Does anyone have any idea where the config setting for TaxonomyClientService.asmx is located or if it can be set, I can find the TaxonomyClientService.asmx file but I can't find the settings in the web.config.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the content length quota on the client wouldn't have much of an effect.You have to change it on the server. The following article describes why: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599489(v=office.14).aspx

You have to adjust the web.config in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebServices\Root (This will affect all web services) or the specific web.config for the TaxonomyService.

Comment: Thanks that certainly make sense now with the 64K limit.  I couldn't find the setting in the web.config to change, but I found instead of the code to run, can use powershell to change the limit.